# ¿Cómo rotar una JLabel en java?

Tags: java

Tengo una aplicación en java en la cual necesito rotar una `JLabel` utilizando los métodos `Graphics` y `Graphics2D`, tengo implementado un `MouseMotionListener` lo cual hace que se pueda mover los `JLabel`.

si puedo rotar las `JLabel`, pero su contenido se pierde.

Este es mi codigo.

```
public class Textos extends JLabel implements MouseMotionListener {

    public void objeto() {

        String valor;

        if (FTexto.conTexto == true) {

            valor = FTexto.TContenidos.getText();

            NewJFrame.la = new JLabel(valor) {
                public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                    Graphics2D gx = (Graphics2D) g;
                    gx.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), 10, 100);
                    super.paintComponent(g);
                }
            };

            NewJFrame.la.setSize(80, 170);
            NewJFrame.la.setOpaque(true);
            NewJFrame.la.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            NewJFrame.la.setFont(new Font(CFuente.getSelectedItem().toString(), Font.PLAIN, Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(FTexto.CTama.getSelectedItem()))));
            NewJFrame.la.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);
            NewJFrame.la.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.LEFT);
            NewJFrame.PPanel1.add(NewJFrame.la, new Integer(3));
            NewJFrame.labels.add(NewJFrame.la);
            NewJFrame.indice++;
            NewJFrame.la.repaint();
            System.out.println(NewJFrame.labels.size());
            NewJFrame.con2 = true;
            NewJFrame.labels.get(NewJFrame.indice - 1).addMouseMotionListener(this);

        } else {
            valor = "";
            NewJFrame.labels.get(NewJFrame.indice - 1).addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

    }
}
```

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

---

Actualización:

Este es el codigo que tengo para crear la `JLabel` y la `Jlabel` esta creada en un `Frame` llamado `NewJFrame.la`.
Como pueden ver tengo el metodo dragged para poder mover las etiquetas

```
public class Textos extends JLabel implements MouseMotionListener {

    public void objeto() {
        String valor;
        if (FTexto.conTexto == true) {
            valor = FTexto.TContenidos.getText();

            NewJFrame.la = new JLabel(valor) {
                protected void paintComponent(Graphics grafico) {

                    Graphics2D graficoNuevo = (Graphics2D) grafico;

                    graficoNuevo.setRenderingHint(
                            RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
                    );

                    AffineTransform at = graficoNuevo.getTransform();
                    Shape figura = graficoNuevo.getClip();

                    double X = getWidth() / 2.0;
                    double Y = getHeight() / 2.0;

                    at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), X, Y);

                    graficoNuevo.setTransform(at);
                    graficoNuevo.setClip(figura);

                    super.paintComponent(grafico);
                }
            };
            NewJFrame.la.setSize(200, 30);
            NewJFrame.la.setOpaque(true);
            NewJFrame.la.setBackground(Color.yellow);
            NewJFrame.la.setFont(new Font(CFuente.getSelectedItem().toString(), Font.PLAIN, Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(FTexto.CTama.getSelectedItem()))));
            NewJFrame.la.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);
            NewJFrame.la.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.LEFT);
            NewJFrame.PPanel1.add(NewJFrame.la, new Integer(3));
            NewJFrame.labels.add(NewJFrame.la);
            NewJFrame.indice++;
            NewJFrame.la.repaint();
            System.out.println(NewJFrame.labels.size());
            NewJFrame.con2 = true;
            NewJFrame.labels.get(NewJFrame.indice - 1).addMouseMotionListener(this);

        } else {
            valor = "";
            NewJFrame.labels.get(NewJFrame.indice - 1).addMouseMotionListener(this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me) {
        if (NewJFrame.labels.size() >= 1) {
            if (me.getSource() == NewJFrame.labels.get(0)) {
                NewJFrame.labels.get(0).setLocation(NewJFrame.labels.get(0).getX() + me.getX(), NewJFrame.labels.get(0).getY() + me.getY());
            }
        }

        if (NewJFrame.labels.size() >= 2) {
            if (me.getSource() == NewJFrame.labels.get(1)) {
                NewJFrame.labels.get(1).setLocation(NewJFrame.labels.get(1).getX() + me.getX(), NewJFrame.labels.get(1).getY() + me.getY());
            }
        }

        if (NewJFrame.labels.size() >= 3) {
            if (me.getSource() == NewJFrame.labels.get(2)) {
                NewJFrame.labels.get(2).setLocation(NewJFrame.labels.get(2).getX() + me.getX(), NewJFrame.labels.get(2).getY() + me.getY());
            }
        }

        if (NewJFrame.labels.size() >= 4) {
            if (me.getSource() == NewJFrame.labels.get(3)) {
                NewJFrame.labels.get(3).setLocation(NewJFrame.labels.get(3).getX() + me.getX(), NewJFrame.labels.get(3).getY() + me.getY());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me) {
        if (NewJFrame.labels.size() >= 1) {
            NewJFrame.labels.get(0).setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
        }
        if (NewJFrame.labels.size() >= 2) {
            NewJFrame.labels.get(1).setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
        }
        if (NewJFrame.labels.size() >= 3) {
            NewJFrame.labels.get(2).setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
        }
        if (NewJFrame.labels.size() >= 4) {
            NewJFrame.labels.get(3).setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.MOVE_CURSOR));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Considero que falta algo de informacion, por ejemplo `Ftexto` Que es? No hay mas informacion sobre las clases que se incluyen/instancian en este programa

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues mas informacion o bien nos indiques un repositorio de github donde se puedan encontrar dichas clases externas `NewJFrame`, `FTexto`, etc. Asi sera mas facil ayudarte

Comment: Nada mas necesito que me den un ejemplo de como rotar una `JLabel` no es necesario que se basen en este ejemplo

Comment: Perfecto, crei que era necesario el ejemplo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Codigo

```
package Interfaz;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class Clase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame ventana = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        ventana.setTitle("VENTANA 1");
        ventana.setSize(300, 300);
        ventana.setLocation(500, 300);
        ventana.setVisible(true);

        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("stackoverflow") {

            protected void paintComponent(Graphics grafico) {

                Graphics2D graficoNuevo = (Graphics2D) grafico;

                graficoNuevo.setRenderingHint(
                        RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                        RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON
                );

                AffineTransform at = graficoNuevo.getTransform();
                Shape figura = graficoNuevo.getClip();

                double X = getWidth() / 2.0;
                double Y = getHeight() / 2.0;

                at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), X, Y);

                graficoNuevo.setTransform(at);
                graficoNuevo.setClip(figura);

                super.paintComponent(grafico);
            }

        };

        label.setVisible(true);

        panel.add(label);
        panel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(100, 10, 10, 10));

        ventana.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        ventana.add(panel);
        ventana.revalidate();
    }

}
```

---

### Resultado

```
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(90), X, Y);
```

[image: Resultado]

```
at.rotate(Math.toRadians(180), X, Y);
```

[image: Resultado]

---

### Explicacion

Ademas del metodo que ya estas usando `paintComponent()`, puedes hacer tambien uso de la libreria [AffineTransform](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=AffineTransform:_Rotaci%C3%B3n_de_un_gr%C3%A1fico_o_imagen_en_java), que como bien puedes ver en dicha documentacion, esta libreria se usa para realizar la rotacion de graficos e imagenes. Asi tambien, para este ejemplo hemos usado la libreria `Math` indicandole como radianes 180, por lo cual hemos rotado el JLabel de un extremo al otro.

Comment: OK @Ivan haz de cuenta que no he dicho nada.

Comment: Hola Ivan cuando la roto a 180 grados si funciona bien pero cuando la pongo a 90 grados se pierde el contenido

Comment: @GiovaniPreciadoOrtiz Ya lo reviso

Comment: El problema que tengo yo creo, es que en mi proyecto yo añado la `JLabel` a un `JLayeredPane` yo creo que funciona diferente a añadirlo a un `Frame`

Comment: @GiovaniPreciadoOrtiz Ya lo he revisado y lo he corregido, en mi caso el problema se encontraba en que no habia usado un JPanel para contener los elementos. Ya funciona la rotacion

Comment: En mi ejemplo yo necesito ponerle un tamaño a la etiqueta si no, no se ve, y también tengo implementado `MouseMotionListener` para mover las etiquetas a través del panel, cuando le pongo 180 grados si funciona pero con 90 no

Comment: @GiovaniPreciadoOrtiz Creo que en ese caso, te sugiero que agregues un ejemplo minimo y verificable de lo que necesitas hacer, ya que en los comentarios dices que solo necesitas un ejemplo

Comment: No es necesario que agregues todo el codigo pero si las partes mas elementales y la descripcion de lo que quieres hacer, asi podtemos ayudarte mas facilmente

Comment: @GiovaniPreciadoOrtiz Es posible que nos compartas un repositorio de github donde se pueda ver el codigo de las clases que estas usando, NewJFrame, FTexto? Ya que como tal es dificil reproducir tu problema. Ya que inicialmente decias que solo necesitabas un ejemplo de rotacion, pero sin las clases que indicas es dificil ayudarte